# How can I make a checkbox group with first and second choice?

Tags: android

In my app the user will select his hobbies from a list.
For now I have a recycler view that show the name and image of the hobby and a check box.

I would like to have only 2 checkboxes enabled(and this I can do it) and when the user click for the first time on one checkbox it will show up `1` instead of the 'check' and when he select the second one there will be `2`.

Also when `1` is unchecked `2` will become `1`

Example code:

```
ArrayList checkedList = new ArrayList();

int first = -1;
int second = -1;
```

-

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomItemHolder itemHolder, int i) {

    final int position = i;

    ...

    if (checkedList.size() > 2){

        itemHolder.checkBox.setClickable(false);
    }

    itemHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked){

                checkedList.add(position);

                if (first == -1){

                    first = position;
                }
                else if (second == -1){

                    second = position;
                }
            }
            else{

                checkedList.remove(position);

                if (first == position){

                    if (second == -1){

                        first = -1;
                    }
                    else{

                        first = second;
                        second = -1;
                    }
                }
                else if (second == position){

                    second = -1;
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add code or describe what you've tried so far to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to assign each "Hobby" a unique ID

```
public class Hobby {
    private final int id;
    // ... other fields, getters
}
```

Then inside your Presentation object (or even just in your adapter for now to get it working) store a list of checked things:

```
List<Integer> checked;
```

When you bind, you can check this list for a few things:

1. If the position's id is the first item in the list (checked.indexOf(item) == 0) then you have your #1
2. If the position's id is the last item in the list (checked.indexOf(item) == 1) then you have your #2
3. If there are two items in the list, and the position isn't one of them (checked.size() == 2 && checked.indexOf(item) == -1) then you know to disable it's checkbox

When you click on an item's checkbox and it's now selected, you add its id to the end of the `checked` list.  When you uncheck it, remove it from the list. By using a list like this, you always guarentee your #1 and #2 are in the right order, and automatically get the repositioning (#2 becoming #1) correct.

Remember to notifyDataSetChanged() whenever you click, after you update your list of checked ids. You can optimize this as well with more specific calls, but it's a little more complicated.

Comment: Ok nice thank you. And how can I change the image of the checked box to "1" or "2"?

Comment: For this a very simple approach would be to use a ViewSwitcher.